# How to sort mongodb collection using a static value and other field value desending

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, aggregate

My colection is a list of products with the following structure

```
    {
      _id
      name
      status  // enum ['active','sold','reserved','pending']
      .
      .
      createdAt
    }
```

What I need is a sort feature along with the status value passed to the system, I ll give an example below

> case: If status = 'active' , Then result should sort as given below

> All products with status active should come first (Active list itself should be in createdAt desc order)

> Remaining products should list createdAt in desc order

Follow the same with all other status value.

If status is empty then list everything in desc order

What I tried is given below

```
    db.products.aggregate([
         {
            $project: {
            "_id":1,
            "name":1,
            "status":1,
            "createdAt":1
            }
         },
         {$sort:{status:"active", createdAt:-1}}, // Error
         {$sort:{status:1, createdAt:-1}}, // Result work but not as expected
    ])
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: since you alredy found an asnwer how about something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/AmASFUgWOVZ

Comment: @cmgchess Thanks for your answer, so your answer will sort the active lists also as createdAt desc
If possible could you please add as an answer with explanation

Comment: what i thought is that you have a `const status = 'something'`. I'm creating a an extra field and it will assign 0 if the field is what you want to get first. else it will be 1. now you can just sort the field and it will give  status 'something' first

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get one solution which is listed below, But I am open to any better solution if exists

```
    db.products.aggregate([
         {
            $project: {
            "_id":1,
            "name":1,
            "status":1,
            "createdAt":1,
            "timeStamp": {
             "$switch": {
                "branches": [
                    { "case": { "$eq": [ "$status", "pending" ] }, "then": 99999999999999 },
                ],
                "default": {"$toLong": "$createdAt"}
                 }
              },
                "createdTime": {
                             "$toLong": "$createdAt"
                           }
              }
         },
         {$sort:{timeStamp:-1, createdTime:-1}}
    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a separate field which specifies which status value to come first

1. Add a field `sortBy` which assigns 0 if it is has the status value that should come first else assign 1
2. Do the usual sorting `sortBy` ascending and `createdAt` descending
3. Remove the newly added field from the output result using `project`

```js
const status = 'active'

db.products.aggregate([
  { $addFields: { sortBy: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$status", status ] }, 0, 1 ] } } },
  { $sort: { sortBy: 1, createdAt: -1 } },
  { $project: { sortBy: 0 } }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AmASFUgWOVZ)